# Problem implementing delays using elapsed time (timestamps)?

Tags: python, delay, sleep

My use case requirements:

- Requirement 1: Loop through Task A, Task B, Task C
- Requirement 2: Skip Task A if performed within the last 5 minutes.
- Requirement 3: If Task A not performed within the last 5 minutes, do not skip during the next loop (or add Task A to a queue?)

I'm using the timestamp approach:

```
import time
from time import perf_counter_ns

intDelayIntervalSecs = 300/1000
tsLastIteration = perf_counter_ns()/1000000000
while true:
    if time.time() - tsLastIteration > intDelayIntervalSecs:
        # perform task A here
        tsLastIteration = perf_counter_ns()/1000000000
    else:
        # perform task B here
        # perform task C here
```

I'm avoiding `time.sleep(n)`, because that will park the program for 5 minutes and block the other tasks.

I'm avoiding threads (`Event.wait()`, etc.) because when the delay interval elapses, I don't want the program to abandon the current task and jump directly to the delayed task.

I've looked at numerous Python references. This elapsed time approach is NEVER mentioned.  This makes me wonder, is there a nuance or problem with this code?

If there is another way to code these requirements, thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you care if timing drifts over time?

Comment: Nope - drift is fine.

Comment: Refactoring to use perf_counter_ns instead of time.time()